# T and R estimation from essential matrix

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, linear-algebra

I created a simple test application to perform translation (*T*) and rotation (*R*) estimation from  the essential matrix.

1. Generate 50 random **Points**.
2. Calculate projection **pointSet1**.
3. Transform **Points** via matrix (*R*|*T*).
4. Calculate new projection **pointSet2**.
5. Then calculate fundamental matrix **F**.
6. Extract essential matrix like `E = K2^T F K1` (`K1, K2` - internal camera matrices).
7. Use SVD to get `UDV^T`.

And calculate `restoredR1 = UWV^T`, `restoredR2 = UW^T`. And see that one of them equal to initial **R**.

But when I calculate translation vector, `restoredT = UZU^T`, I get normalized **T**.

`restoredT*max(T.x, T.y, T.z) = T`

How to restore correct translation vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand! I don't need real length estimation on this step.
When i get first image, i must set metric transformation (scale factor) or estimate it from calibration from known object. After, when i recieve second frame, i calculate normilized T, and using known 3d coordinates from first frame to solve equation (sx2, sy2, 1) = K(R|lambda*T)(X,Y,Z); and find lambda - than lambda*T will be correct metric translation...

I check it, and this is true/  So... maybe who know more simple solution?

Comment: This sounds like the solution proposed by Bae et al. in *Computational Re-Photography* (2010), I have googled around and found no different approach.